# Garbled Festival Sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I'm using the Festival speech synthesizer under Ubuntu 10.04 like:

```
echo '(SayText "hello world")' | esddsp festival --pipe
```

This works perfectly on 32-bit systems, but on 64-bit machines it's unreliable. Usually, it'll work correctly the first time, and then subsequent calls with sound completely garbled, and I'll get this error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/esound/libesddsp.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object 'libesd.so.0' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.
```

How would I fix this? I've Googled, and it seems this is not a new error, but the problem seems to popup in different distros for different apps, and the solutions are usually convoluted and involve recompiling the entire audio stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. If you did not remove Pulseadio (Ubuntu's default audio system and ESD replacement) you may have more success in doing this:

pasdp instead of esddsp:

`echo '(SayText "hello world")' | padsp festival --pipe`

Pulseaudio's automagic alsa swallower:

`festival '(SayText "hello world")'`

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to fix this issue forever. The first works perfectly. The second sounds tinny and garbled and bypasses my mixer, as I heard it on my laptop's speakers even though I had headphones plugged in.

Comment: You're welcome. Thank you too for bringing this up. I now use `festival '(SayText "%t, by %a")'` at the gmusicbrowser 'Now playing' plugin at track changes...